# Prove $f(x) = x^{2}$ is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$  with $f(x) = x^2$, show $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \frac{1}{3}(b^{3}-a^{3})$

Here is my trial:
Let $X =(x_{0},\dots,x_{n})$ be a partition on $[a,b]$, let $t_{i} \in [x_{i-1},x_{i}], i=\{1,\dots,n\}$
Then $|\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(t_{i})\triangle_{i}x - \frac{1}{3}(b^{3}-a^{3})| = |\sum_{1}^{n}t_{i}^{2}\triangle_{i}x - \frac{1}{3}\sum_{1}^{n}x_{i}^{3}-x_{i-1}^{3}| \\
 = |\sum_{i=1}^{n}[t_{i}^{2} - \frac{1}{3}(x_{i}^{2} + x_{i}x_{i-1} + x_{i-1}^{2})] \triangle_{i}x|$

But now I got stuck... can someone help me out?

Comment: A hint : in your last expression, use $t_i^2 = \frac{3}{3}t_i^2$ to have three sums, then you can bound the differences $|t_i-x_i|$ by $\Delta_i x$ which is enough to guarantee these three sums tends to zero.

Comment: @M.Boyet Sorry I still dont understand it .. Now I have $|t_{i}^{2} - x_{i}^{2}|,|t_{i}^{2} - x_{i}x_{i-1}|,t_{i}^{2} - x_{i-1}^{2}$.. Which identity I should use to make them bounded by $\Delta_{i}x$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this answer has been given many times, but I am too lazy to find a reference, I prefer to write it again. It is useful to prove first that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\tag{1} $$
holds. That can be done in many ways, for instance by induction or by the hockey-stick identity:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[2\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}\right] = 2\binom{n+1}{3}+\binom{n+1}{2}.\tag{2}$$
For the function $f(x)=x^2$ over the interval $(0,1)$, the upper and lower Riemann sums for uniform partitions are given in terms of
$$ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)^2,\qquad \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)^2 \tag{3} $$
and the limit of both, as $N\to +\infty$, equals $\frac{1}{3}$ by $(1)$. At last,
$$ \int_{a}^{b}x^2\,dx = \int_{0}^{b}x^2\,dx - \int_{0}^{a}x^2\,dx = (b^3-a^3)\int_{0}^{1}x^2\,dx\tag{4} $$
proves the claim.

---

**Addendum**. With a geometric flavour (i.e. integrating along sections), $\int_{a}^{b}x^2\,dx$, if $0<a<b$, is just $\frac{1}{\pi}$ times the volume of a frustum of a cone with height $b-a$ and radii of the bases given by $a$ and $b$. [The formula](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Frustum/Frustum.cone.html)
$$ V = \frac{\pi h}{3}(R^2+Rr+r^2) $$
is known since the Babylonian period and can be easily proved through similarities, once we know that the volume of a cone (or pyramid) is $\frac{1}{3}h\cdot A_{\text{base}}$. Through Cavalieri's principle and the property of linear maps of proserving ratios of volumes, the whole question boils down to finding the volume of a pyramid given by the convex envelope of a face of a cube and the center of the same cube. That trivially is $\frac{1}{6}V_{\text{cube}}$ by symmetry.

Comment: Thanks, but for this question I am required to prove it just using the defintion.. which means I cannot use your last expression..

Comment: @ZHANGYUE: then just replace every occurence of $\frac{k}{N}$ in $(3)$ with $a+\frac{k}{N}(b-a)$. You may still compute the upper and lower Riemann sums in a explicit way through $(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $0\leq a<b$.(or $a<b\leq 0)$ (For the case $a<0<b$, we may come up with the equation $\int_{[a,b]} f = \int_{[a,0]} f + \int_{[0,b]} f $.)

Following the notation above, we may observe ${x_{i-1}}^2 < x_ix_{i-1} < {x_i}^2$ for each $i=1,\cdots,n$ so that $${x_{i-1}}^2 < \frac{1}{3}({x_{i-1}}^2+x_{i-1}x_i+{x_i}^2)< {x_i}^2$$

with ${x_{i-1}}^2 \leq {t_i}^2 \leq {x_i}^2$ obviously.( for $a<b\leq0$, "$<$" would be "$>$")

Then, $$|{t_i}^2-\frac{1}{3}({x_{i-1}}^2+x_{i-1}x_i+{x_i}^2)|<|{x_i}^2-{x_{i-1}}^2|={x_i}^2-{x_{i-1}}^2$$($-{x_i}^2+x_{i-1}^2$ for $a<b\leq0$ )

Consequently, if we take $d=d([a,b])$ as $max\{\Delta_1 x,\cdots,\Delta_n x\}$,

the last term you wrote can be bounded as follows.

$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \left({t_i}^2-\frac{1}{3}({x_i}^2+{x_{i-1}x_i}+{x_{i-1}}^2)\right)\Delta_i x\right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left|{t_i}^2-\frac{1}{3}({x_i}^2+{x_{i-1}x_i}+{x_{i-1}}^2)\right|\Delta_i x $$
$$\leq d \sum_{i=1}^n \left|{t_i}^2-\frac{1}{3}({x_i}^2+{x_{i-1}x_i}+{x_{i-1}}^2)\right| \leq d \sum_{i=1}^n \left| {x_i}^2 -{x_{i-1}}^2\right| = d|b^2-a^2|$$

As a result, $\sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i)\Delta_i x \rightarrow \frac{1}{3}(b^3-a^3)$ as
$d\rightarrow0$, regardless of the choice of $\{t_i\}$. (Rimann integrability ?)

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = x^2$ is continuous everywhere, and hence Riemann-integrable. QED.

Comment: I guess OP wants a proof by definition.

Comment: I figured as much; my answer was just to be cheeky.

Comment: Well, in that case define the function $\mathrm{I}$ from the space of step functions to $\Bbb R$ as to coincide with Riemann, show it is linear continuous, hence it satisfies an inequality of the form $|\mathrm{I}(s)| \leq \lambda \|s\|;$ thus, it has a unique extension towards the completion of the space (the reglèe functions). By doing that, you proved that every function sufficiently regular has integral; bonus, the method works well for vector functions too.